# Returning an Int32 from managed code to Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi

I've used the information in this post [Delphi - Accessing data from dynamic array that is populated from an untyped Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/628965) and others, plus Robert Giesecke's [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) to write some great code - thanks everyone. For example, I've written methods which return a complicated byte stream from C# back to Delphi. I'm having trouble, however, doing the simplest thing - returning an integer from a function call.

So, I define this prototype in Delphi:

```
TReturnIntFunc = function(AnInteger: Integer): Integer; safecall;
```

and this in C#:

```
[DllExport("NegateInt", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
static Int32 NegateInt([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] Int32 AnInteger)
{
  return AnInteger * -1;
}
```

As with the other methods I've written, I dynamically load the C# DLL, find the function just fine, but when I execute it from Delphi, it throws an Exception with the message "Exception in safecall method".

Any clues anyone? I can and have marshal back an out or ref integer, just not as a return value.

Comment: Safecall does argument list re-writing. It changes the number of arguments of your function. That's why you get a runtime error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safecall and StdCall is not the same thing - try using StdCall on the Delphi side as well.

Comment: Many thanks. I just **knew** I was making some rookie mistake, just couldn't see it. I don't know why I used "safecall" in the first place. It worked fine for my void methods, just not 'functions'. Anyway, I rebuilt all with stdcall both sides of the divide and it all works now.